# What are bitcoin Pool APIs?

Tags: blockchain, mining-pools, api, raw-data

I contacted a website and asked them where they get their data for crypto like Bitcoin, as I am trying to find the place for the most up to date and reliable data on Bitcoin and other crypto. They had sent me an email back saying they get their data from block explorers and pool apis. Block explorers were pretty self explanatory and easy to find and pull data from. But I wasn't 100% confident in my idea of what a Pool API was. Is it an API that is connected to a specific mining pool that gives you real time data? How do I set it up and where does the data get sent to? Or am I completely misunderstanding what it is?

Answer (score 0):

Most pools offer some kind of proprietary API endpoint that offers basic stats about the pool or stats about a specific user/rig in that pool.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it an API that is connected to a specific mining pool that gives you real time data?

Yes.

> How do I set it up and where does the data get sent to?

The current mining pool breakdown by hash rate is shown here on [mempool.space](https://mempool.space/mining). You'd have to go to the site of each mining pool to see whether they offer an API, what data that API provides and how to use it. For example the Braiins API docs are [here](https://help.braiins.com/en/support/solutions/articles/77000433512-api-configuration-guide). When you use an API your machine requests data from someone else's server and if successful the server returns this data.